# Can't configure RBAC to users in EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, rbac

I have deployed EKS using `eksctl` following [this docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-eksctl.html).

As the user who created the cluster I have full access control.
Trying to grant `system:masters` permissions to a specific user doesn't work this [way](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html):

```yaml
kubectl edit -n kube-system configmap/aws-auth
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapAccounts: |
    - "111111111111"
  mapRoles: |
    - groups:
        - system:bootstrappers
        - system:nodes
      rolearn: ***
      username: ***
  mapUsers: |
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::***:user/test-user
      username: test-user
      groups:
        - system:masters
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  ...
```

Logging in as the `test-user` and executing `kubectl get pods` I receive:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "arn:aws:iam::***:user/test-user" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
```

I have read somewhere that `mapAccounts` maps the users to `system:authenticated`, but I couldn't verify it in AWS docs.
I have tried to created different `clusterRole` and `clusterRoleBindings` and attaching them to the `test-user` but nothing works...

How can I grant access to the specific `test-user` user, or in general give full access (modify `system:authenticated`) to my group in IAM?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using `rolearn` instead of `userarn` under `mapUsers:`.

Replace that and it should work.

To apply a new configuration to the RBAC configuration of the Amazon EKS cluster, run the following command:
`kubectl apply -f aws-auth-cm.yml`

Then you should be able to login as test-user.